# Looping functions over dates - Python

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I am not the most proficient in Python so apologies for any hideous code.

I have a csv file containing daily spot rates of different libor curves of different tenors. I have two functions where the first takes the spot rates of one libor curve at one date, and the second takes those rates from the first function and calculates the forward rates:

```
def importdata (fileloc, date, name, max_maturity=None):
    'Imports data from a given location, date and name'
    data = pd.read_csv(fileloc) # file location 
    data = data[ (data['date']) == date] # getting the date of the curve
    data =  data.loc[:, data.columns.str.startswith(name)] # getting the curve wanted at the date
    data = data.T # Transposing the data
    data = data.reset_index()
    data.columns = ['maturity','spot rate'] # renaming columns
    data['maturity'] = data.maturity.str.rsplit(n=1).str[-1]
    if max_maturity:
        data = data.iloc[:data.loc[data.maturity.str.contains(max_maturity,na=False)].index[0]+1]
    return data


def interpolate (dataframe, TENOR, freq):

    'Gets the forward rates from given tenors (X) and corresponding spot rates (Y)'
    
    terms= dataframe["maturity"].tolist()
    rates= dataframe['spot rate'].tolist() 
    
    dc = ql.Actual360()
    settlement_days = 0
    if Curve =='3M USD' or Curve == '6M EUR' or Curve == '6M GBP': 
        
        helpers = []

        for term, r in zip(terms, rates):
            if Curve == '3M USD': 
                swapIndex = ql.UsdLiborSwapIsdaFixAm(ql.Period((term)))
                helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(r/100, swapIndex))
            elif Curve == '6M EUR':
                swapIndex = ql.EuriborSwapIsdaFixB(ql.Period((term)))
                helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(r/100, swapIndex))
            elif Curve == '6M GBP': 
                #swapIndex = ql.SwapIndex('GBP Libor', ql.Period(term), settlement_days, ql.GBPCurrency(), ql.UnitedKingdom(), ql.Period('6M'), ql.Following, dc, ql.GBPLibor)
                swapIndex = ql.GbpLiborSwapIsdaFix(ql.Period((term)))
                helpers.append(ql.SwapRateHelper(r/100, swapIndex))
            
    elif Curve == 'EONIA' or Curve =='SONIA' or Curve =='FF':
       
        OIS_helpers = []
        
        if Curve == 'EONIA': 
            calendar = ql.TARGET()
            EONIA = ql.OvernightIndex("EONIA", settlement_days, ql.EURCurrency(), calendar, dc)
           
            for i in range(len(terms)):
                tenor = ql.Period(terms[i])
                rate = rates[i]
                OIS_helpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), EONIA)) 
           
        elif Curve =='SONIA': 
            calendar = ql.UnitedKingdom()
            SONIA = ql.OvernightIndex("SONIA", settlement_days, ql.GBPCurrency(), calendar, dc)
            
            for i in range(len(terms)):
                tenor = ql.Period(terms[i])
                rate = rates[i]
                OIS_helpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), SONIA)) 
                    
        elif Curve == 'FF': 
            calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
            FedF = ql.OvernightIndex("FedF", settlement_days, ql.USDCurrency(), calendar, dc)
            
            for i in range(len(terms)):
                tenor = ql.Period(terms[i])
                rate = rates[i]
                OIS_helpers.append(ql.OISRateHelper(settlement_days, tenor, ql.QuoteHandle(ql.SimpleQuote(rate/100)), FedF)) 
         
        helpers = OIS_helpers
    
    curve = ql.PiecewiseSplineCubicDiscount(0, ql.TARGET(), helpers, dc)
    curve.enableExtrapolation()                                                                           
    
    days = ql.MakeSchedule(curve.referenceDate(), curve.maxDate() , ql.Period(freq)) #Frequency
    
    if Curve == '3M USD' or Curve =='FF':
        fwds = [
            curve.forwardRate(d, ql.UnitedStates().advance(d,ql.Period(TENOR)), dc, ql.Simple).rate()*100
            for d in days
        ]
   
    elif Curve =='6M EUR' or Curve == 'EONIA': 
        fwds = [
            curve.forwardRate(d, ql.TARGET().advance(d,ql.Period(TENOR)), dc, ql.Simple).rate()*100 
            for d in days
        ]
    
    elif Curve =='6M GBP' or Curve == 'SONIA':
        fwds = [
            curve.forwardRate(d, ql.UnitedKingdom().advance(d,ql.Period(TENOR)), dc, ql.Simple).rate()*100
            for d in days
        ]
  
    fwdsdic = {Date:fwds}
    fwdcomp = pd.DataFrame(fwdsdic)
 
    ALL_FWD = fwdcomp.to_csv('1y1y.csv', header = '1y1y')     
    
    return fwdcomp;
```

An example of `data` which is used an input to `interpolate`:

```
    maturity    spot rate
0   1Y  0.105
1   18M 0.19
2   2Y  0.265
3   3Y  0.41100000000000003
4   4Y  0.542
5   5Y  0.655
6   6Y  0.7509999999999999
7   7Y  0.833
8   8Y  0.904
9   9Y  0.966
10  10Y 1.021
11  12Y 1.093
12  15Y 1.157
13  20Y 1.182
14  25Y 1.18
15  30Y 1.162
16  40Y 1.073
17  50Y 1.01
```

What I want to do is to calculate these forward rates for one curve, but for all the dates in the CSV file, and then save these rates to a new csv file. So far what I have done is import the entire CSV file into pandas and then create a for loop for all the dates:

```
AllDate = all_data['date']
for dt in AllDate.iteritems():
    data = importdata(locationAll, dt, Curve)
    interpolate(data, '1y', '1y')
```

I get this error:

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 1 elements, new values have 2 elements
```

I'm unsure as to where I have gone wrong, any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I have changed the for loop to this:

```
AllDate = all_data['date']
for dt in AllDate.iterrows():
    data = importdata(location, dt, Curve)
    interpolate(data, '1y', '1y')
```

I get this error message instead:

> AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Here is a picture of my input file if it helps:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTXi8.png)

Answer (score 0):

The error you got says what's wrong. `pandas.DataFrame.interitems()` returns two values (label and content) but you gave it only one variable `dt` to write it to.

You can read the [docs here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html) for an example.

Comment: I edited my question, I realised interitems() is for columns whereas my dataset is in rows